# Refreshing spring application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm running spring application (version 4.3.3) and trying to refresh application context beans including [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) changes.

After changing `spring.profiles.active` property (at runtime) and calling [refresh](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#refresh--) method on application context, beans defined within profiles are not getting refreshed.
After changing property in the configuration file followed by application restart everything is correct.

How can I refresh the context respecting profile change?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. Some sample code will definitely help in fixing it. Can you add some sample code?

Comment: What do you mean by *"beans defined within profiles are not getting refreshed"*? Do you want beans from **all** profiles being refreshed or only within current active profile?